# Javascript function

Tags: javascript, function, console.log

there is such javascript code:

```
function a() { 
  a = 3; 
  return a;
}
console.log(a());
console.log(a());
```

After execution it prints out: 3, Type error. Could anybody explain why, please

Answer (score 11):

**You have a scope issue**

Because you didn't use "var" you are overriding the global "a" variable (*used to be your function*) with a number (3).

When you try to execute it a second time, it's no longer a function but a number, which throws the type error.

```
function a() {
  a = 3; // you just over-wrote a() 
  return a;
}

console.log(a()); // 3, but now "a" === number, not function
console.log(a()); // ERROR, you treated "a" as a function, but it's a number
```

**what you want**

```
function a() {
  var a = 3; // using var makes "a" local, and does not override your global a()
  return a;
}

console.log(a()); // 3
console.log(a()); // 3
```

Using **var** is recommended almost always inside a function, otherwise you're polluting, or worse overriding, global variables.
In JS, var enforces your variable into the local scope (your function).

*Note that using var in the global scope still creates a global variable*

Comment: I absolutely recommend [this book](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/tree/master/scope%20%26%20closures) from the You Don't Know Js Series

Comment: Good link! @LionelDamiánT is right. I've been speaking about "scope" without actually mentioning it. The fundamental issue in OP is scope related. Made that a little clearer in answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you were trying to set `a` as a variable, then `var` is needed in front. Because you didn't do so, it is exposed to the global scope, in which it is part of the `window` object, and you can access it with `window.a`. So, the best thing to do is to change the first body line of your function to say: `var a = 3`.

Comment: thanks guys for your explanation it was a test question in an online example of questions asked in one company